# TCL - Find all warning count in a file

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to find out all warning count contains in a file.
The line starts with Warning contains a warning code.
I tried it with regexp and able to get count for single warning, not able to get for all. Please explain me algorithm to perform below taks.

```
Warning (abc_10) .... <explanation of warning>
Warning (abc_11) .... <explanation of warning>
Warning (abc_10) .... <explanation of warning>
Warning (abc_13) .... <explanation of warning>
Warning (abc_11) .... <explanation of warning>
Warning (abc_10) .... <explanation of warning>
.
.
.
.
Warning (abc_15) .... <explanation of warning>
```

in output I need below information

```
abc_10 5 (Assuming abc_10 occurred 5 times in a file)
abc_11 2
abc_13 1
abc_15 4
```

Please help me to proceed further.

Comment: show us the regex that you have tried so far that isn't working

Comment: You have a regular expression that matches one of these lines and extracts the ID? That's extremely useful for making the overall solution! Please show it.

Comment: You can break down the warnings with `^(Warning\s+\()([abc_\d]+)(\).+)` It would be useful to see what regex you've already tried

Comment: `set fp [open "warning_file.txt" r]`
`set abc_10 0`
`while {[gets $fp line] != -1} {`
   `if {[regexp {^Warning\s.*} $line]} {`
        `if {[regexp {.\(abc_10\)\s*} $line] } {`
        `incr abc_10`
        `}`
   `}`
`}`

puts $abc_10

Comment: When adding information, please do so in the question text by editing it. Code in comments is very hard to read, and very easy to overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script uses the pattern `\(([^)]+)` (match from a literal left parenthesis, capture a set of one or more characters excluding a right parenthesis) to capture the warning codes, and then enters them into a frequency array (i.e. one where each value is the frequency of a given key/name occurring.

```
unset -nocomplain warnings
set fp [open warning_file.txt]
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {\(([^)]+)} $line -> key]} {
        incr warnings($key)
    }
}
close $fp
```

Then you can just print the array:

```
% parray warnings
warnings(abc_10) = 3
warnings(abc_11) = 2
warnings(abc_13) = 1
warnings(abc_15) = 1
```

Documentation:
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[parray](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: I implemented this exactly the same. I used the non-greedy regex `^Warning \((.+?)\)`

Comment: @glennjackman: I tend to avoid non-greedy matching on account of my being easily confused. ;)